# Adding to EE Publish/Edit Form

Tags: control-panel

Can anyone give me some advice on how I can add some specific content to a publish/edit screen? I'm specifically wondering if this is possible using hooks and an extension.

Right now I'm hooking in to the `publish_form_entry_data` hook and running some actions based on certain parameters. I'd like to push a notice to the publish/edit form depending on conditions in my extension (which I've already got working.)

**Is it possible to push a notice to the publish/edit form from an extension?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that either using `ee()->cp->add_to_head('cssurlhere');` or `ee()->cp->add_to_foot('jsurlhere);` allows me to modify the form when used with the `publish_form_entry_data`hook.